# Showing a search bar in Android

Tags: android, uisearchbar

I'm having trouble when trying to show the search bar at the top of my app. I just want this bar to be visible for the hole application (in all the activities) even when the app starts, with no need for the user to press a button, I'm trying to use android's searchable function. Here's what I've got so far:

**manifest.xml**

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".BigImageView">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
    <!-- declare the default searchable Activity for the whole app -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
           android:value=".BigImageView" />

</application>
```

**res/xml/searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
```

Can I accomplish this or does the user need to press a buttons to invoke the search bar?

Answer (score 2):

You could put

```
onSearchRequested();
```

in `onResume()` - but the search bar would hide if another component will get the focus.

If that's not what you want, you should implement your own search bar (i.e. with AutoCompleteTextView).

Comment: is there a way to set focus to the search bar always, so that it is always visible?

Comment: putting the onSearchRequested(); in the onCreate() method worked, now i can see the search bar when the app starts but it seems that i have to do that for all my classes and it seems that there's no way to declare this onSearchRequested() in one place only to avoid writing it in all of my classes. I'm i right?

Comment: you create an (abstract) base activity (where you put in that logic) from which you extend all your all your activities. Then you don't need to copy/paste the same logic everywhere.